# count how many times dict values repeated

Tags: python, optimization

assume I have dictionary like this

```
d = {
    'key_1': 2,
    'key_2': 2,
    'key_3': 2,
    'key_4': 5,
}
```

I want to create a dictionary telling me that how many times each value was repeated:

```
result = {
    2: 3,
    5: 1,
)
```

my solution was

```
from collection import defaultdict

r = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for value in d.values():
    r[value] +=1
```

my question is, Is there a simpler cleaner soltion for this question (instead of 3 lines of code can I have a one liner solution?)

Comment: `Counter(d.values())`

Comment: Asking for suggestions on working code is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Check out the `Counter` class @Chris_Rands suggested: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes that was what I was looking for